# TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, passwords

I have this code and I need to check if the password is Check if  password is not all uppercase
                                                        Check if password is not all lowercase
                                                        Check if password is not all numbers
                                                        Check if password has special character
                                                        Check password length (minimum 8)

```
   while not (name := input('Enter name: '))[0].isupper():
    print('Error: Name must start with a capital letter')
while not (surname := input('Enter surname: '))[0].isupper():
    print('Error: Surname must start with a capital letter')
while not (username := input("Enter username: "))[0].isalpha():
    print('Error: Username must start with a letter')
while not (password := input('Enter password: '))[0].isupper()[0].islower()[0].isnumeric():
    print('Error: Note that the password cannot be only numbers, letters in capital or lower')
```

I am getting this error TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

`:=` is a [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), you have to use a `==` to compare your expressions